# Kubernetes : Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: kubernetes

My Kubernetes cluster is in private network and I have local tunnelling setup done to get connected via bastion Host.

Have created a kubernetes service account and fetching the secret of it, I have created `~/.kube/config` file which is required for authentication.

```
+ kubectl --context=default-context get pods -v=8 --kubeconfig=/.kube/config --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
I0522 06:45:05.156725    1051 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /.kube/config
debug1: Connection to port 8443 forwarding to XXXXXXXXXXX port 443 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [direct-tcpip]
I0522 07:00:37.781155    1046 round_trippers.go:446] Response Status:  in 10000 milliseconds
I0522 07:00:37.781212    1046 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I0522 07:00:37.781262    1046 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get https://localhost:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
I0522 07:00:37.781342    1046 helpers.go:234] Connection error: Get https://localhost:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
F0522 07:00:37.781400    1046 helpers.go:115] Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
debug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 6
debug1: channel 1: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8443 for XXXXXXXXXXX port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 50736 to 127.0.0.1 port 8443, nchannels 5
Killed by signal 1.
```

**Can someone please explain the reason for this TLS handshake timeout to start my debugging.**

Comment: Can u run with `kubectl get pods -v=8` and share the logs ? We can see which endpoint is failing

Comment: You bastion host is ablr to reach the cluster? Did you tried a telnet test in the destination IP and Port?

Comment: @KoopaKiller Yes we have connectivity from bastion to destination server.

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian , the -v=8 option has been added and log have been added to the question now.

Comment: Can you check `kubectl cluster-info`. What is the IP of master IP address ? is it accessible from your machine ?

Comment: It returns same error TLS handshake timeout for cluster info too. My .kube/config points to localhost as tunnel i established runs in the background. Do, we have any other recommended documentation to access k8s cluster via bastion host?

Comment: So you are using ssh tunnel to reach the kubernetes port? Or how are you doing this tunnel? Please add this information in your question.